# LocalDB of SQL Server Express 2014 not found and Error thrown while installing SQLLocalDB.msi

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I got the URL to install SQLLocalDB (2014) and downloaded `SQLLocalDB.msi`
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299

I am getting the following error while installing SQLLocalDB.msi (of 2014)

> Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Express LocalDB
>   Installation of this product failed because it is not supported on this operating system. For information on supported configurations, see the product documentation.

I have already installed SQL Server 2012 and 2014 and `SqlLocalDB` of 2012 on my system.

```
C:\Users\abcd>sqllocaldb v
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (11.0.3000.0)
```

Now I am not able to install `SQLLocalDB`.

I don't know why I am not able to install `SQLLocalDB.msi`

(Note: I have admin rights, Windows7 prof(sp1), Inter(R) Core(TM)i5-2450M CPU @2.5GHZ, RAM-8GB, HD free space - 170GB)

What could be the reason for the failure? Could someone help?

Comment: My guess is you downloaded the 64-bit version but have a 32-bit operating system. Or vice versa, but that's less likely.

Comment: Since the error message says it's *not support on this operating system* - ***what*** operating system are you trying to install this onto??

Comment: @AaronBertand : Thank you very much!! Mine is 64 bit operating system and downloaded 32 bit installer. Got the 64 bit installer and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As AaronBertand said in the comments. I tried to install 32 bit installer in 64 bit operating system, so it failed. Got the 64 bit installer and it worked.
Thanks AaronBertand!!